# SSMS 2012 System.OutOfMemoryException (client side) and SQL Prompt (debug info incl)

Tags: sql, ssms, redgate, ssms-2012, red-gate-sql-prompt

Some background: I've been encountering this memory exception within SSMS 2012 since it was released coupled with Red Gate's SQLPrompt (this exception never happens in my SSMS 2008R2 on the same laptop).

I was originally encountering these exceptions daily (SSMS2012 and SQLPrompt) which forces me to close and reopen SSMS (along with everything I was working on). Months ago I stumbled upon a support thread that pointed possible add-on's as being the cause so I **uninstalled** my only add-on (SQL Prompt, but did not uninstall the rest of the developer's bundle) and went many months *without* a single exception much less the System.OutOfMemoryException exception.

Once SP1 was released for 2012 I applied it and reinstalled SQL Prompt again (the latest version) to see if maybe the issue had been addressed and within 7 hours of development time I was greeted again with the infamous System.OutOfMemoryException.

Through out all of this I've been opening tickets with Red Gate and submitting debug logs where they see the exception but since the memory exception doesn't explicitly list SQLPrompt they won't escalate the issue to the development team. Prior to this specific exception SQL Prompt however is throwing numerous exceptions (some listed below) within the SSMS 2012 IDE (Visual Studio 2010). I believe that the memory exception is symptomatic of an issue with how SQL Prompt manages cached data and eats up the available memory for SSMS which eventually throws an exception as a result.

I've learn how to defer this issue and how to reproduce it and it is directly related to two variables:

1. Connecting and working on multiple instances in SSMS (Object Explorer and Query windows). I.e. Connected to 7 instances netted the exception within 2-3 hours.
2. Returning result sets from multiple instances. This includes queries used by SSMS to return information to the IDE and results returned to the individual query windows.

The more instances I'm connected to the fast the exception is raised which leads me SQL Prompt's caching all of the object information per instances. Once the memory exception is raised the situation degrades until SSMS crashes completely (unless I close it first).

What I am after is how to collect more/better information to submit to Red Gate to correct this issue. This is where I need your help.

Laptop: HP Elite book 8440
RAM: 6GB

Current OS:
Win 7 Enterprise Ed Sp1

Here are some of exceptions caused by SQL Prompt:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."   

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Implementation.BinaryStringRebuilder.GetLineNumberFromPosition(N/A,N/A)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Implementation.TextSnapshot.GetLineFromPosition(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Implementation.TextSnapshot,N/A)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextBufferAdapter.GetLineIndexOfPosition(N/A,System.Int32,System.Int32&,System.Int32&)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.VSScriptProvider.PositionFromIndex(RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.VSScriptProvider,System.Int32)
RedGate.SqlPrompt.Metadata.Script.ScriptProviderBase.GetText(RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.VSScriptProvider,System.Int32,System.Int32)
RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.NewEngine.SqlPromptEngine.GetCandidates(RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.NewEngine.SqlPromptEngine,System.Int32)
RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator.get_GetSuggestions(RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator)
RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.AutoCompleter.m_FilterChanged(RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.AutoCompleter,RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator,System.EventArgs)
RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator.OnFilterChanged(RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator)
RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator.set_Index(RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator,System.Int32)
RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator.set_CaretPosition(RedGate.SqlPrompt.Engine.PromptEngineEmulator,N/A)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonUI.Editor.EditorWindowBase.SetEngineCaretPosition(RedGate.SQLPrompt.SSMSUI.SSMSEditorWindow,N/A)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonUI.Editor.EditorWindowBase.UpdateUIPrompts(RedGate.SQLPrompt.SSMSUI.SSMSEditorWindow)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.VSEditorWindow.OnTextViewCommandExec(RedGate.SQLPrompt.SSMSUI.SSMSEditorWindow,RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor,RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.CommandExecEventArgs)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor.AfterCommandExecute(RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor,RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.CommandExecEventArgs)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor..(RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor.)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonUI.Utils.ErrorDialog.Do(System.Action)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor.(RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor,System.Guid&,System.Uint32,System.Uint32,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)
RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor..(RedGate.SQLPrompt.CommonVS.Editor.TextViewMonitor.,System.Guid&,System.Uint32,System.Uint32,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A)

System.ArgumentException    00:05:14.7510000    "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"   

#mMc.#JQub.#OQub(#mMc.#JQub,N/A,System.Uint32,#mMc.#k3ub&)
#mMc.#JQub.#z26.#8Di(#mMc.#JQub.#z26)
RedGate.SQLSourceControl.Engine.SmartAssembly.ExceptionReporting.ErrorReporterBase.Do(RedGate.SQLSourceControl.CommonUI.Forms.ErrorDialog,System.Action,System.Predicate`1<System.Exception>,System.Boolean)
RedGate.SQLSourceControl.Engine.SmartAssembly.ExceptionReporting.ErrorReporterBase.Do(RedGate.SQLSourceControl.CommonUI.Forms.ErrorDialog,System.Action)
RedGate.SQLSourceControl.CommonUI.Forms.ErrorDialog.Do(System.Action)
```

And here is the Memory Exception:

[image: Exception thrown in result set]

```
System.OutOfMemoryException <null>  

System.Text.StringBuilder.set_Capacity(System.Text.StringBuilder,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEDiskStorageView.set_MaxNumBytesToDisplay(N/A,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEDiskDataStorage.GetStorageView(N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEResultSet.StartRetrievingData(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEResultSet,System.Int32,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.ResultSetAndGridContainer.StartRetrievingData(N/A,N/A,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.ResultsToGridBatchConsumer.OnNewResultSet(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.ResultsToGridBatchConsumer,N/A,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QESQLBatch.ProcessResultSet(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QESQLBatch,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QESQLBatch.DoBatchExecution(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QESQLBatch,System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QESQLBatch.Execute(N/A,N/A,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEOLESQLExec.DoBatchExecution(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEOLESQLExec,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QESQLBatch)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QESQLExec.ExecuteBatchCommon(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEOLESQLExec,N/A,N/A,System.Boolean&)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEOLESQLExec.ExecuteBatchHelper(N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.QueryExecution.QEOLESQLExec.ProcessBatch(N/A,N/A,N/A)
.BatchParser.ThunkCommandExecuter.ProcessBatch(N/A,N/A,N/A)
```

Again, to be clear, I don't know if the other exceptions are related or not but the memory exception **only** happens with SQL Prompt installed.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Might be better suited to the [RedGate forums](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/index.php)

Comment: To me this forum is a super-set of the Red Gate forum so I'd stand a better chance of getting advanced help here. Besides, I've been dealing with Red Gate support for many months with no resolution.

Comment: As the use of the 2012 SSMS coupled with Redgate's SQLPrompt is spreading in the department so is this exception. A peer DB developer who just switched to using SSMS 2012 with SQLPrompt is now crashing.

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue here, with SSMS 2012 and 2014.

Comment: If the pattern for you is different then it was for me try to come up with a method to reproduce it. Either way open a ticket with Red-Gate; they need to know it is affect more people.

Answer (score 1):

At this point RedGate has finally admitted the issue is that the SQL Prompt plug-in is working in-process with the 32-bit SSMS client and eventually chokes the memory resulting in the out-of-memory exception.

Their response to a fix for this would be "maybe" in a year or so which, when you are paying for annual support, is a slap in the face. I've since refused to pay for further support for 2 existing Tool-belt licenses over this issue, an issue that I have fought with since 2012, until they correct this. If this is affecting you then, and if you can, do the same and vote with your wallet to motivate them to make this fix a higher priority.

If and when that day comes I will update this answer post with the version information of the corrected build of SQL Prompt that no longer operates within the 32-bit memory space of SSMS.exe.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is Disabling Code suggestions in SQL prompt, then I can run the same query and then get the results.
I can then Enable Code suggestions in SQL prompt and the error stays away for a while.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try limiting the number of columns as described in this post and see if it helps?
http://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/94413-sql-prompt-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1364757-disable-sql-prompt-on-certain-databases

Comment: I've tried limiting and disabling caching in the past but the exceptions didn't stop then.

Comment: Another problem with this suggestion is that I never know what databases and servers I will be working on so in order for this to work I would have to micro manage this setting constantly. For a tool sold a professional database tool it fails to live up to that when used by an actual database professional when it is crashing SSMS constantly.